# How to capture desktop on windows so that it would capture both directX and normally rendered parts of screen?

Tags: c++, windows, directx, screenshot

Simple example - on one side we see camera rendered via standard software rendered "Input" on other hand (labeled "Output") rendered via some directX stuff (at least it seems to me) :

[image]

So what function is provided by windows api or DirectX api  for capturing such mixed scenes?

Comment: Hard to understand what you are looking for. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I don't think you can, because the other stuff is just grabbed from the memory on the graphics card, but the DirectX or OpenGL stuff isn't rendered into memory the same way.

Comment: hit stamp then paste in paint ;)

Answer (score 2):

TightVNC Server can do it, you may want to look into what they are doing. From a simple glance through their source code it looks like they are creating a virtual screen that mirrors the primary screen.
Specifically though, look into the
`CreateCompatibleDC` and `CreateDIBSection` API's

Comment: do they use a mirror driver though?

Answer (score 1):

As I known, there is not a direct way to capture DirectX render area, although we can see that on the screen. Because the real render action(aka render instruction) happens in hardware layer. So the API in standard SDK cannot know the finally render result, which lead to the black square.

The only way to do this maybe put your hope on the Render layer(such as DirectX engine) itself can support output interface as well as underlying render action. So I suggest to check some documentation to find if there indeed is.

Answer (score 1):

DirectX can present to a limited subsection of the window that you give it, enabling you to create small regions of DX content in larger windows.